# How to find the order of the algorithm?

Tags: java, big-o, nested-loops

I have to find the order or these algorithms. The computations are independent of n.

```
for (int pass = 1; pass <= n; pass++){
   for (int index = 0; index < n; index++){ 
     for(int count = 1; count < 10; count++){     
    }
   }
 }
```

and the second part is that i'm supposed to replace 10 with n in the inner loop. I feel like both will be O(n<sup>3</sup>) but i'm not too confident with that answer. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Once you replace `10` with `n` in the inner loop, it will be `O(n3)`, since you have three nested loops, all dependent on `n`.

As it stands *now,* it's `O(n2)` since the inner loop with ten iterations takes a constant time, independent of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You're running each loop n times (after putting n into the 3rd loop). The loops are nested on 3 levels so you will execute the instructions in the inner-most loop n<sup>3</sup> times.

Your answer is correct: it's O(n<sup>3</sup>). It's actually Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) as both lower and upper limits are n<sup>3</sup>.

---

Without replacing the 3rd loop, the answer is O(n<sup>2</sup>) (or Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)) as the number of inner-most iterations is contant for each outer iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you may apply the following, and you'll get the exact number of iterations:

[image]